# WP theme mega menu woo taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, megamenu

I am working on a custom wordpress theme and using woocommerce. In the woocommerce i am having some custom taxonomies for my products ex. Brands, Designers.

I need to build a mega menu and display the Brands/Designers as submenu. Should i use navwalker to build that kind on menu? Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on how your mega menu will look like. For example i have mega menu where i needed to be on 5 columns with specific order of the items and different number of items per column. I just created 5 different menus and that was all.

Comment: I need to have a dropdown SHOP menu item and it's children will be 4 columns of a custom taxonomy each one. I don't want to create different menu for each taxonomy, since i need all taxonomy items to be showing up.